# Why is the "Pending edit" count zero based?

Tags: support

Is the number beside the edit link supposed to say 0 when there are edits waiting for approval? I would have thought it should say **edit (1)**

[image: pending eidts]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note the end of the tooltip, it mentions:

> nobody has voted on this edit yet.

The number after edit is showing the votes on the edit, [as I read here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/105764/145350):

> The number is the total number of votes, not the number of accept votes. If a post has 1 accept and 1 reject vote, it will say `edit (2)`, which is useful information (it lets people know the suggestion is contested). If the format is going to change it would be nice if the number of rejected votes is still displayed somewhere

Comment: This mainly seems to be focused to lower reputation users. on the main site I saw edit (0) and was able to bring it to edit (1) by voting to accept it.